# Creating dynamically a file name in C

Tags: c, string, file, server, client

I'm working on a client, server project. I receive a response from the server where I have to create two files. The first file is a .html file and the second file is .png file. I parse the response and I try to dynamically create the files in a `while` loop.

```
...
FILE *fwrp;
char *response = malloc(MAXDATASIZE * sizeof(char));
memset(response, '\0', sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);
char *r = &response[0];


while (fread(field, sizeof(field), 1, fpr)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATASIZE; i++) {
        *r = field[i];
        r++;


//Some unecessary code...

                    if (strstr(response,"file=")){
                    char* newFileName = strchr(response, '=');
                    newFileName++;
                    fwrp = fopen(newFileName, "w");
                    data = false;
//...
```

I hope I didn't cut too much necessary information. **The problem** is the following: The files are created. Also with the right content. 
The problem just the dynamic name of the file. One time the name should be `ok.png`, but instead it is `'ok.png'$'\n'` 
The same problem for the html file. The name should be `example.html` but is `'example.html'$'\n'`

**Already tried** to print the names before they are created. They have the right format when they are printed. And I tried to allocate the memory with `strdup`, but it did not work for some reason. Anybody have an idea why this problem appears?

**SOLUTION:**

For those who are interested. Here is my solution

```
int receiveResponse(int sockfd) {
int sdw = dup(sockfd);
FILE *fpr = fdopen(sdw, "r");
FILE *fwrp;
int lenOfRecord = 0;
bool data = false;
bool status_checked = false;
bool first = true;
unsigned char field[MAXDATASIZE] = {0};
char *response = malloc(MAXDATASIZE * sizeof(char));
memset(response, '\0', sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);
char *r = &response[0];




while (fread(field, sizeof(field), 1, fpr)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAXDATASIZE; i++) {

        *r = field[i];
        r++;



        if ((field[i] == '\n') && (data == false)){

            if (strstr(response, "status=") && (status_checked == false)){
                status_checked = true;
                char* status = strchr(response,'=');
                status++;
            }

            if (strstr(response, "len=")){
                char *len = strchr(response, '=');
                len++;
                char *ptr;
                lenOfRecord = strtol(len,&ptr,10);
                data = true;
                first = true;
            }

            if (strstr(response,"file=")){
                char* tmp = strchr(response, '=');
                tmp++;
                char* newFileName = malloc(strlen(tmp) * sizeof(char));
                memcpy(newFileName, tmp, strlen(tmp)  * sizeof(char));
                newFileName[strlen(newFileName) - 1] = 0;
                fwrp = fopen(newFileName, "w");

                free(newFileName);
                data = false;
            }


            free(response);
            char* response = malloc(MAXDATASIZE * sizeof(char));
            memset(response, '\0', sizeof(char) * MAXDATASIZE);
            r = &response[0];
        }


        if (--lenOfRecord == 0){
            data = false;
            fflush(fwrp);
            fclose(fwrp);

        }

        if ((data == true) && (first == false)) {
            fputc(field[i], fwrp);
        }

        if ((data == true) && (first == true)){
            first = false;
        }



    }


}



}
```

So the problem was solved with this modification

```
 newFileName[strlen(newFileName) - 1] = 0;
```

Comment: Where is "response" coming from? Clearly you're expecting it to look like "file=name", when in fact it looks like "file='name'...". If it's the latter, you'll have to parse that yourself.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the response looks like this file=example.html

Comment: i have also edited my question. so that you see where the response comes from

Comment: Can you string compare between **ok.png** and content of **newFileName** pointer just before you call fopen. What is the platform you are working on windows +VS, linux + gcc?

Comment: Can you print newFileName before you call fopen() ? If there is unwanted chars at the end, reprocess there, before calling fopen() , could fix the problem but it does not explain why you have the problem.

Comment: @chandola . I work with linux platform. i dont know why i should string compare ok.png and newFileName.

Comment: @BobRun I printed the filename before i created it. the filename was without the special characters. but when i created the file the special characters appeared in the filename. but i found a solution. i will put the solution up where i my question is

Comment: @Ikarus Console may not display all the characters. I suggested that to confirm that there are no such characters which are leading to the problem. You can either string compare or print string in hex(each character in hex not char ie 0x41 for A and so on). I will suggest to investigate everything with the string name that you give to fopen.

Answer (score 0):

1. I've no idea, why are you copying readed `field` content into `response` instead of reading strictly into `response`. Additionaly, you didn't show the declaration of `field`.
2. Probably you should take the better care on count of readed chars (returned by `fread()`): it can be negative (means: error), not only positive or 0.
3. What about zero-termination?

So, my proposition is:

```
//...
// for better readability
#define MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE (MAXDATASIZE * sizeof(char))

// below: added 1 byte for preserving the proper string termination ('\0' byte)
#define RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE (MAXDATASIZE + 1)

FILE *fwrp;
char *response = malloc(RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE);
memset(response, '\0', RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE);

int readOffset = 0; // offset for reading the next chunk
int readCount; // count of readed characters/bytes

// below: return of fread() can be positive, 0 if no more data, or negative if error
while ((readCount = fread(response + readOffset, MAX_RESPONSE_SIZE - readOffset, 1, fpr)) > 0) {
    readOffset += readCount;
}

//Some unecessary code...

if (strstr(response, "file=")) {
    char* newFileName = strchr(response, '=');
    newFileName++;
    fwrp = fopen(newFileName, "w");
    data = false;
//...
```

Comment: thx for your code. ya field is not really necessary you are right. my idea why i constructed field and response was that field is the "uncompleted response" from fread. because fread doesnt give me the whole response from the server at once. so i read from fread until the command tells me the whole response from the server is read. My "response" variable is constructed until a "\n" occurs. So I just always parse the "response - line" which makes my parsing logic a little easier. but up there I will post my solution